Curl - File format issue : Linux versus Windows
I have the following .dat file in Linux :
U|205003509999|PMBARTICLE2|02000000|02000000|3|PM|F. AJDJDJ|K|00000.0000|K|1|00000002|10999|3500002|||||0|0||00000.0000|150|
It is a flat file composed of a few columns separated by | character.
I am using the following command:
curl -X POST https://AAAAA.XXXX.YY/vcloud/v1/stores/tata.toto/items/files/BO-PRIX.dat -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:c0jdjdjdjdjdjdjzzziz" --data-binary "file.dat"
With the same file and command, in Windows, the command works perfectly.
With the same file and command, in Linux, the command works perfectly **BUT **the format of the file received on https side is not expected as it is seen as a file without any columns.
I tried to convert the file with iconv from utf8 to several formats and also to replace --data-binary by --data in the command line but it didn't help.
I need the format of the file to be OK from Linux.

What do you mean by "it is seen as a file without any columns"? Have you tried changing the line ends (\x0a versus \x0d\x0a)?

I have got this error in my destination application only if I send the file from Linux: "
The column count defined in configuration is 25. But the line contains 1 columns"

Since the columns are defined by the | character, it would appear that curl is messing those up.  But I can't imagine a case where it would do that.

You'll have to use data-binary as --data-binary "@file.dat"
The @ symbol before file.dat, tells curl to read the file's contents as the data to be uploaded.
